# Difficulty with fortran variable scope

Tags: fortran

I have intialized one variable in one of the fortran functions. I am using it in another function. But the value is not remains same. In other function call I am getting garbage value. How do i maintain the initialized value.

Ex:

```
entry a()
num_calls=0

entry b()
num_calls= num_calls + 1
```

From entry "b" i am getting num_calls as some garbage

Comment: Is num_calls locally or globally scoped?

Answer (score 5):

In classic Fortran (Fortran 77 or earlier), you'd ensure that num_calls is defined in a common block - probably a named common block.

```
COMMON /magic/ num_calls
```

I've not used Fortran 90, so I don't know what extra facilities it has.  It likely retains named common blocks for backwards compatibility, but likely provides something better too.

I cheated, too, and used an implicit declaration of the variable.  In full, I should write:

```
INTEGER*4 num_calls
COMMON /magic/ num_calls
```

Answer (score 4):

For FORTRAN 77, Jonathan Leffler's method will work - as he points out, Fortran 90 and onward also supports `COMMON` blocks.  However, since you have access to a Fortran 90/Fortran 2003 compiler, then there is no reason to use a `COMMON` block - leave them in the ash heap of history along with computed `GOTO` and `ENTRY`.

The Fortran 90 method for storing a group of related variables (and functions) is no longer the `COMMON` block but a `MODULE`.  For your code, this is relatively straightforward:

```
module count_calls

    integer :: num_calls = 0

end module count_calls
```

Then, in your subroutines where you want to use num_calls, add

```
use count_calls
```

to either the subroutines themselves or the containing scope (i.e. a `program` or another `module`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `num_calls` outside of either subroutine so that its lifetime is unrelated to either subroutine call. Someone who actually speaks FORTRAN can provide you some sample code...

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the variable with the "save" attribute.  That way the variable lives between calls.  There are compiler options to mark all variables as "save" since old compilers did this by default or depending upon optimization level.

```
    integer*4, save :: num_calls
```

It is a standard feature of most languages that local variables go undefined when they go out of scope.

Comment: Though, most historical FORTRAN compiler did allocate the local in a static area rather than on the stack, making the save statement optional and encouraging bad practices...